# Oracle oci_connect AL32UTF8 php utf8 weird characters

Tags: php, oracle, oci8

I've been scratching my head for a while now, and I'm hoping that someone can push me in the right direction.

I have an Oracle DB that contains account information like Name, Surname, etc., and if I run the following (pseudo-)code:

```
<?php

$db = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myHost)(PORT=myPort)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=myServiceName)))"; 

oci_connect("user","pass",$db,'AL32UTF8');

$query="

SELECT

//tried this
lastname AS LAST_NAME

//tried this:
(convert(lastname,'AL32UTF8')) AS LAST_NAME

FROM
    SomeDb
WHERE
    SomeId = 1234 
";

$stid = oci_parse($c1, $query);
oci_execute($stid);

$row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS);

echo $row['LAST_NAME']; //returns Ã�Â¼

echo utf8_decode($row['LAST_NAME']); // returns Ã¼r

echo utf8_encode($row['LAST_NAME']); // returns Ã�Â�Ã�Â¼
```

it returns `ü` characters back as: `Ã�Â¼`, while `ë` characters are being displayed correctly.

I've checked the `NLS_CHARACTERSET` of the Oracle server which is set to: `AL32UTF8`.

I also checked the Apache charset config:

```
curl -A "Mozilla/4.0" http://localhost -I

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 05 Sep 2017 13:08:01 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

I tried to set internal coding:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8"); // this seemed to be default UTF-8.
```

I tried several `setenv` values, but it seems nothing really works. What could be the problem? Am i overlooking something?

Additional info:

```
PHP -v  
PHP 5.6.30-0+deb8u1

OCI8
OCI8 Version 2.0.8
```

Comment: Why ist it '<asterisk><aasterisk>AL32UTF8<asterisk><aasterisk>'? IS that really your in your source file or did only you want to emphasize it?

Comment: I wanted to emphasize it .. i'll edit the post, thanks!

Comment: Are you using HTML - with what page charset?  Have you checked PHP's default_charset setting?

Comment: Hi @ChristopherJones it's a standalone PHP file supposed to be triggered by crontab, so there is no HTML involved but i checked the PHP default_char setting which is UTF-8. I also tried to set the header and enviroment settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition; I tried the following piece of code to find the correct encoding which gave me always `UTF-8`. If i moved the `UTF-8` further back in the array it always gave me `ISO-8859-1`. So it turned out useless.

```
$encodings= array( 'UTF-8', 'ASCII', 'ISO-8859-1', 'ISO-8859-2', 'ISO-8859-3', 'ISO-8859-4', 'ISO-8859-5', 
        'ISO-8859-6', 'ISO-8859-7', 'ISO-8859-8', 'ISO-8859-9', 'ISO-8859-10', 
        'ISO-8859-13', 'ISO-8859-14', 'ISO-8859-15', 'ISO-8859-16', 
        'Windows-1251', 'Windows-1252', 'Windows-1254');

echo mb_detect_encoding($string, $encodings, true);
```

Further research didn't come up with a cause or solution, so i decided to have the source characters in the Oracle database adjusted to the correct character.

I know it's not really the solution i wanted but since the amount of characters that were showing this weird translation were very low that was the quickest solution.

Thanks to all that have been thinking along with me.

Regards,

Frans